# Fulltext search with <> characters

Tags: mysql

Having problems getting the following query to work. I want to match the actual string " to control word relevance.

```
SELECT * FROM (table)
WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST ("+<foo><![CDATA[1850]" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

When I run this it returns almost all records in the database, not just those which match the exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can not use special characters in full text search indexes. It is limited to TEXT. (Words to be exact. For example you can have a list of most common words to be excepted form this index). You have to use LIKE if you are searching for pieces of code with special characters.

Comment: Exactly. That's the whole idea of full text indexing: being able to find stuff with tools that *understand* natural language.